# Symfony2 Assetic not working with multiple javascript file with the * sign

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, assetic

I use Symfony2 and the assetic Bundle. (probleme when using the * sign to ask assetic to take all files)

Form what I have read here and there assetic allow to use multiple javascript file.

This work just fine when when I write all the file right before the <'/html> tag:

```
{% javascripts
    '@MySiteBlogBundle/Resources/public/js/test1.js' 
    '@MySiteBlogBundle/Resources/public/js/test2.js'
    '@MySiteBlogBundle/Resources/public/js/test3.js' 
%}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

but the same code, doesn't work if instead of listing the file, I use the * (just like this:)

```
{% javascripts
    '@MySiteBlogBundle/Resources/public/js/*'
  %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
 {% endjavascripts %}
```

with the *, it works only depending on the pages which are displayed. I did all my javascipt test on class which are on my main twig template. And thoses class are displayed on all pages... So all test should be working.

Anyone ever had such probleme when using this * sign with assetic?

Thanks for any comment/help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed only two problems with assetic earlier.

First, in production mode you have to dump them (php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod) before using. Okay, this is not a problem but you shouldn't forget it.

Second, if you use the * sign to load all JavaScripts then the order of your scripts will be alphabetical and this can break a few dependencies among script files. This is the reason I usually don't use the * sign.

Comment: thanks. You are right since I change the order of my file (by changing their names) I got different results. I might do like you and avoid the * sign. By the way any idea on how to avoid thoses dependencies in javascript files?

Comment: You cannot avoid them completely. But I can recommend this module: https://github.com/ustream/jms This may help you, though it is a heavyweight solution.

Answer (score 0):

After few hours with the same issue, I realized you need to:

1. create symbolic links (A.K.A. *symlinks*) or copy of your bundles by command:

   bin/console assets:install

   or

   bin/console assets:install --symlink
2. in your definitions, use `bundles/mysiteblog/js/*` rather than `@MySiteBlogBundle/Resources/public/js/*` (you will see your bundle path in WEB directory after Step 1.